# How to add a parent directory to SVN?

Tags: svn, directory

Say I have a directory structure like this

```
dir1
   dir2
   dir3
```

`dir2`is already under version control, whereas `dir1` is not. Now I realize that I would like to have `dir1` under version control as well (and maybe later on `dir3` etc.) How can I do this and reflect the changes correctly in the repository?

If I just move `dir2` out of `dir1`, add `dir1` to SVN and move `dir2` back into `dir1`, this will probably destroy the version history of `dir2`. What makes it even more complicated is that `dir2` contains many files which are not under version control (they are ignored), so `dir2` cannot be (fully) recreated from the repository.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, re-importing dir2 will not save the history of your existing dir2.

This should do the trick (assuming *path* is the url repository):

1. svn mkdir *path*/dir1
2. svn mv *path*/dir2 *path*/dir1

Comment: Fails with `svn: No support for repos <--> working copy moves`.

Comment: You tried to mix working copy paths and repo URLs in a way that didn't work. Try either all working paths or all URLs.

Comment: OK, then one should change the second item above, otherwise it's misleading.

Comment: Sorry, I had surrounded the last *path* with <> which made it not appear. I've corrected it.

Comment: I guess this is the cleanest solution, but it requires a full check-out. In my case this was not feasible.

Comment: I'm not sure if a svn switch would let you keep the already checked out files.
In general, the branch contents should not be so big that a complete checkout is a problem. If you want to use svn effectively, data transfer should not be a limitation.

Answer (score 1):

try `svn add --parents dir1/dir2`

Answer (score 0):

- create `dir1` besides `dir2`
- move `dir2` into `dir1`

You can do this on the server (by using URLs) or in your working copy (by using file system paths). In the latter case you will have to commit afterwards.

Comment: I tried this on the server (i.e. `svn mkdir url/dir1; svn mv url/dir2 url/dir1`) which succeeded. But when I tried `svn up` I get `svn: Failed to add directory 'dir2': object of the same name already exists`?

Comment: You will have to make a fresh checkout into a new location.

Comment: I would like to avoid checkouts (see question). Thus I tried to do this locally, I now have `dir11` on the same level as `dir2`, but `svn mv dir2 dir11` gives `svn: Unable to lock 'dir11'`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility, although it might not be exactly what you're looking for: [SVN externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html).

1. Check in `dir1`.
2. Add `dir2` as SVN external to `dir1`s properties:

-

```
$ svn propget svn:externals dir1
dir2  svn://repository/dir2
```

Answer (score 0):

This code execute all parents as you want

```
svn add --force * --auto-props --parents --depth infinity
```